# Is there a cryptography primitive for public/private keys such that only keys from a predefined set will be valid

Tags: signature

I am trying to accomplish the following:

- $Alice$ is an authority that can provide a secret $x$ to $Bob$, $x$ will enable $Bob$ to generate a public/private key pair $(p,q)$ which he can then use to sign messages. $Alice$ will not be able to sign messages as $Bob$.
- Anyone can trivially verify that the public key $Bob$ used was authorized by $Alice$.

My initial thought is that one could implement a rough version of this by requiring $Bob$ to submit his public key to $Alice$ then collect a digital signature on the public key which is then included as an addendum to his public key. The only problem is that now $Alice$ knows $Bob$'s public key.

Comment: You've just described how certifying authorities work in such protocols as TLS. Why is it a problem if Alice knows Bob's public key? This still does not allow Alice to sign messages as Bob (which would require Bob's private key).

Comment: If it's an issue that Alice knows Bob's public key, well, Alice to do a blind signature of Bob's public key...